# Parameters of ARMA model

Tags: time-series, arima, white-noise

In my professor's notes, it is written that if the variable $y$ is explained with an ARMA($p$,$q$) model, then $y_t$ (i.e. $y$ at time t) depends on the most recent $p$ lags of its own value and the most recent $q$ lags of a white noise process.

I understand the fact that $y_t$ depends on the past $p$ values of $y$, but I don't quite understand the $q$ lags of a white noise process. My understanding of a white noise process is that it is a sequence of random variables over time, where each random variable in the sequence is i.i.d. and has a mean of zero.

Can someone explain what it means to depend on $q$ lags of a white noise process? I think it means that at the last $q$ points in time, the value taken by the particular white noise process explains the value of $y$, but I also don't understand the difference between depending on a white noise process and simply having an error term. Is it that the last $q$ values of the white noise process explain the size of the error term for $y_t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AR(1) model looks like this:
$y_{t} = \rho_{1} y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}$

Where $\epsilon_{t}$ is your innovation/error term/white noise process.  Note that $y_{t}$ depends on $\epsilon_{t}$ but not $\epsilon_{t-1}$, $\epsilon_{t-2}$, etc.  The error term is not correlated across time.

An ARMA(1,1) model looks like this: 
$y_{t} = \rho_{1} y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t} + \theta_{1} \epsilon_{t-1}$

An ARMA(1,2) model looks like this:
$y_{t} = \rho_{1} y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t} + \theta_{1} \epsilon_{t-1} + \theta_{2} \epsilon_{t-2}$

For the ARMA process, $y_{t}$ and $y_{t-1}$ will be correlated not just because of the $\rho_{1} y_{t-1}$ term but because of the $\theta_{1} \epsilon_{t-1}$ term.  The errors do not disappear immediately, they die out over time.  $y_{t}$ depends directly on not just one realization of the white noise process, but on the $q$ past realizations.